# SQL query to get data between a particular date and the latest date in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, validation

I have a queried data in SQL Server from various tables in which I need to know that I want to fetch data between a date 1 Jan 2017 (start date) and the latest data present in the start date column.

Comment: Is it MySQL or sql-server ?

Comment: Provide sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, 3-5 rows) and desired output for this data.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses `MAX` as an analytic function to find the latest start date:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(start_date) OVER () AS max_start_date
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '20170101' AND max_start_date;
```

Comment: … wouldn’t it be simpler as “ SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE start_date >= '20170101' “?

Comment: @lptr Your suggestion is not the logic stated in the OP, which wants a range between 2 dates.

Comment: …but any value of start_date is always <= max(start_date)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know that I want to fetch data between a date 1 Jan 2017 (start date) and the latest data present in the start date column.

This is another way of saying that you want all data on or after 2017-01-01.  So:

```
where start_date >= '20170101'   -- or if you prefer '2017-01-01'
```